# Como alterar a conexão com o banco de dados utilizando o Sequelize+MySql+Express dependendo do parâmetro enviado no request?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Por exemplo, ao receber um parâmetro no request igual a db1, no controller preciso que utilize a string de conexão db1

Ao iniciar o servidor NodeJS já é carregado a configuração feita no arquivo config.json com os dados da conexão

Os bancos possuem o mesmo schema, são iguais na estrutura

O projeto tem a estrutura padrão criada pelo Sequelize:

/routes

/controllers

/models/index.js

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../bin/configuration/config.json`)[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file =>
    (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) &&
    (file !== basename) &&
    (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Quase isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30202056/change-database-connection-depending-on-route-in-express-js-with-sequelize

Comment: Achei algo aqui que revolve: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3190